# Is it possible to enforce nullability of template?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to have something like this to runtime check a nullable value isn't null in debug builds, a debug assert, just like C/C++ projects convention of having such different level of asserts,

```
val <T> T.debugAssertNotNull: T
    get() = this ?: throw NullPointerException("A debug only assert has happened")
```

This works fine except it was just more nice if this T automatically was able to only accept nullable values or to hint at least when a not null value is passed

```
"123".debugAssertNotNull
```

or when "?." accidentally is used instead ".",

```
val a: String? = null
val b = a?.debugAssertNotNull
```

was passed used, is that possible or every not null type is inherited from its nullable variant anyway thus making this impossible?

Comment: "every not null type is inherited from its nullable variant" Yes, `T` is a subtype of `T?` for any non-nullable `T`.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing the `!!` operator, if I understand correctly?

Comment: You seem to be looking for [assertNotNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/kotlin.test/assert-not-null.html)

Comment: There is only one level of asserts in JVM (assertions enabled/disabled, see https://herongyang.com/Java/Assertion-JVM-ea-and-da-Options.html); not sure about other kotlin targets

Comment: This is debug only check and is replaced with noop in release, this type of checks is popular in other environments. If you are certain this isn't possible just put it as an answer and I will mark that as accepted. Thanks :)

Comment: I believe it is not possible at compile time, but it should be possible at runtime. So you will still be able to write `"123".debugAssertNotNull` and it will compile, but when executing this code, it will throw an exception, log some warning, etc. If this is what you need then I can add an example.

Comment: I was looking for a compile time one but this should be interesting, great and acceptable to me as well! (guess starts with reified template? That's creative and I didn't think about it!), I don't see why not anyway, thanks!